# WPF: designer won't set custom property

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my WPF appp, I created a custom control by subclassing TextBox. I then added a DependencyProperty called BorderWhenRequired (the border to use when the TextBox represents a required field), like so:

```
public class TextBoxEx : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderWhenRequiredProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "BorderWhenRequired", typeof(Brush), typeof(TextBoxEx),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Brush), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender)
    );

    public Brush BorderWhenRequired
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BorderWhenRequiredProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BorderWhenRequiredProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I then created a resource that holds the brush value for the border, and a style for the control:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="RequiredControlBorderBrush">Purple</SolidColorBrush>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type implementations:TextBoxEx}">
    <Setter Property="BorderWhenRequired" Value="{StaticResource RequiredControlBorderBrush}" />
</Style>
```

but the designer is showing me:

```
ArgumentException: '#FF800080' is not a valid value for the 'MyNs.Common.Controls.Implementations.TextBoxEx.BorderWhenRequired' property on a Setter.
```

I tried defining the resource `RequiredControlBorderBrush` as a Brush, Color and SolidColorBrush, but I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. In case anyone comes across this: I made a careless mistake. All Color properties in my custom class where defined as System.Drawing.Brush, when they should have been System.Window.Media.Brush.

Comment: I will, but according to StackOverflow's rules, I can only do that tomorrow.